# Angular JS Form management

Tags: django, forms, angularjs

I am using Django, and would like to use Angular on my forms. Is there anyway to bind to form elements without having to explicitly write out each input element and add a ng-model?

I would like to be able to do this:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="text" name="password" />
</form>
```

And access the username/password in $scope as myForm.username and myForm.password, without having to do this:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="myForm.username" />
    <input type="text" name="password" ng-model="myForm.password" />
</form>
```

This would be useful when using Django's form builder, which automatically outputs forms based on the model they are based on, and saves having to write out and modify each form when changes are made.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this yesterday... I would do it like this:

forms.py

```
form_name = 'myForm'  #or some other logic to get form class name
username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'ng-model': '%s.username' % form_name}))
```

or use https://github.com/jrief/django-angular

```
from django import forms
from djangular.forms.angular_model import NgModelFormMixin

class ContactForm(NgModelFormMixin, forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField()
    # more fields ...
```

This will output:

```
<input id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" ng-model="subject" />
```